# Custom shapefile in Geoserver's ImageMosaic plugin being overwritten

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I'm using GeoServer's ImageMosaic plugin and I would like to be able to assign my own sort order to my tiffs.

I have a store that links to a folder of GeoTiffs, and the folder also contains a .shp .prf, .shx and .dbf file. They all have the same name as the store and are in the folder containing the tiffs. I have generated the shapefile (and sidecar files) in FME where I am easily able to generate the shapefile and import the sort attributes from a database.

However, when I save the store, GeoServer automatically generates a shapefile index and overwrites the shapefile I've added (in doing so, getting rid of my "sort" attribute).

I have read that GeoServer should not overwrite a shapefile if one exists in the containing folder, so I'm at a loss.

Am I missing a properties file (and if so, what should it should look like)?

Comment: Did you try using "UseExistingSchema=true" in the indexer.properties? See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html